# Unable to access variables from a files with "includes" in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook that is required to read variables from a yaml file. I am using include_role in my play so can't seem to leverage vars_files. I also tried vars_from but that doesn't seem to work either. The variables live in ~promupdate/vars/hostgroup/templates/test.yaml folder

I tried  the playbook below

```
- hosts: "{{ test }}"
  serial: "100%"
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: promethium_update
      vars:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        wrapped: "{{ lookup('file', /promupdate/vars/hostgroup/templates/item.yml) | from_yaml }}"
      with_items: {{ templates }}
```

This is the error i get.

```
fatal: [prom-test]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'PromUpdater' is undefined"}
```

Has anyone figured out a way on how to achieve this?

I tried both ansible 2.5 and ansible 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with `include_vars`

```
- hosts: "{{ test }}"
  serial: "100%"
  tasks:
    - name: include vars first
      include_vars: path_to_var_file
        
    - include_role:
      name: promethium_update
```

Comment: How do I run both of these as a part of the same loop? These need to run on the same "item" and import different files based on the item this is running on. I think this would work if the file was static.